# "Real-time questions for [your sites]" on Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, realtime-questions

I'm using the tab "Real-time" often lately on [Stack Exchange Home](http://stackexchange.com).

Could there be a functionality to monitor some specific sites, not all together?

Comment: You mean like the homepage of pretty much each and every site? (pretty much because Stack Overflow alone doesn't have that)

Comment: For example, when a new question come up on [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions), the page will indicate that - one click and you will see the new questions.

Comment: I mean, For examples my site where I am in are: StackOverfflow, Super User and Serverfault. When I go on Real time tab, I see just these answers from these sites.

Comment: The live update was taken off of the big sites intentionally because the traffic is too constant. Most of the SE sites already do this.

Comment: @Catija - I think the OP is looking for a realtime feed like the one on se.com, only scoped to only the sites the user has profiles on.

Comment: @Oded Right, For example I have 2 site on my profile: StackOverflow and DBA. I go on the stackexchange home, I see  a real-time with topic comes just StackOverflow and DBA.

Comment: Oh ok. I'm sorry, I hope team will improve the real time.